# JSON access not working

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to access a JSON file from my HTML file, and I'm using JQuery:
`$.getJSON( "en.json", function( data ) {   console.log(data.age);      });`

This doesn't seem to work though. I'm using Xampp to host my local server, and I read somewhere that JSON doesn't work when stored locally. Could it be an issue related to that?

Thank you

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            alert();            
            $.getJSON( "en.json", function( data ) {
                console.log(data.age);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test">
            Hi
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "add-school" : "Add School",
    "age" : "Age",
    "age-months" : "Age (in months)",
    "age-years" : "Age (in years)",
    "all-classes" : "All Classes",
    "audio": "Audiometry",
    "bmi" : "BMI",
    "bp" : "BP"
}
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: No, there is no error in console.

Comment: What is `console.log(data);`

Comment: Share your code and json file.

Comment: `console.log(data.age)` is just to test whether the data is being read from the JSON

Comment: Check the network tab and see request preview,

Comment: Yes, I see that the JSON file is also in the list.

Comment: Where exactly is your JSON file located? Alternatively you can try and access it from a .js file as shown in bottom-most example here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: My JSON is located in the htdocs folder of xampp, the same folder as my HTML folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks okey. Make sure that your **json** file is at same location with your **html** file. If it isn't change the path in `$.getJSON()` function.

Comment: They are in the same location, but it is still not working.

Comment: I test the same code and everything is working. Can u send me the tree of your project?

Comment: If your html code is in html folder put `en.json` file in that folder.

Comment: what is print `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: `console.log(data)` prints nothing. None of the statements I enter inside the `getJSON()` function are executed

Comment: Try to check errors:
`$.getJSON("en.json", function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
                .error(function(xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                })
            );
`

Comment: This is giving an error `TypeError .error is not a function`

Comment: $.getJSON( "en.json", function( data ) {
                console.log(data.age);
            }).error(function(xhr) {        
  console.info(xhr) 
 });

Answer (score 1):

I was able to view the result "Age" in the console. I am running Tomact Apache 7.0 version on my machine and saved both the files (.html and .json) in the same folder inside the webapps folder.

For viewing the webpage the url I used is

http://localhost:8080/Foldername/Json.html 
and I could see the result of console.log (data.age) in the console

Comment: I don't understand why this wouldn't work! Just to be clear:

1. I am using XAMPP

2. I have both the `abc.html` and the `en.json` files inside the `htdocs` folder of xampp

3. I navigate to `localhost/abc.html`

4. I can see the message "Hi", but the console is empty

Comment: No, there are no errors. I added an `alert()` inside the `$.getJSON...`, and there is no alert appearing, so I think it is not even entering the function call.

Comment: Not sure what is going on ? I tried the steps in the answer and could see both the alert and the result in the console.